# Specific plugin script not working on subdomain

Tags: plugins, multisite, jquery, subdomains

Currently I'm working on a local copy of site which uses multi site feature.
And there's a strange thing with jQuery script.
On main site it works completely correct, but on subdomain the part of this script doesn't work.

For example:

```
demo.example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=incsub_event
```

This works great, but this doesn't work:

```
example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=incsub_event
```

Here's the console:
[image]

Here's the function which doesn't work:

```
$("#eab-eab-start_recurrence-button").click(toggle_recurrence_settings);

function toggle_recurrence_settings () {
    var text = $("#eab-eab-start_recurrence-button").val();
    var alter = $("#eab-eab-start_recurrence-button").attr("data-eab-alter_label");
    $("#eab-eab-start_recurrence-button").val(alter);
    $("#eab-eab-start_recurrence-button").attr("data-eab-alter_label", text);
    if (!$("#eab_event-recurring_event").is(":visible")) show_event_recurrence();
    else hide_event_recurrence();
    return false;
```

}

What could be the reason of such strange behavior?

Comment: what is the point of asking a question about your code without showing it? please edit the question and include relevant code

Comment: The problem is that the code is not mine. It's just a script from plugin.
But I will add a part of code which doesn't work to the question.

Comment: It would be best to direct this question to the plugin's developer who would be  able to give you better support for this scenario.

Comment: plugin related questions should be asked at their support venues

Comment: The problem is mostly related to the multisite feature, because on the main domain it works perfectly.

Comment: You always have the option to continue waiting for an answer that are not likely to come here, or get an answer from people that are familiar with the code. Your snippet as you posted it, without any context, is not enough to even make an educated guess

Comment: The problem is that the plugin is no longer supported for me. Also I'm trying to fix it by myself, but was wondering whether someone had a familiar situation. That's why I posted this question here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the function itself was declared before the initialization of button that wasn't working.
So the replacing of button init before the function declaration resolved the issue.